# Dynamically altering SQLAlchemy's relationship cascade settings during runtime?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm working on a script to copy complex structures of SQLAlchemy models with relationships from one database to another, using SQLAlchemy's `session.merge()` and `cascade='merge'`. Currently the model relationships have hard-coded options describing their cascade options:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    related_model = relationship(RelatedModel, cascade='save-update, merge')
```

I would however like to be able to modify the `cascade` options dynamically using code, adding or removing `'merge'` based on the arguments provided to the script. Can this be done somehow?

I have been unable to find anything in the documentation and my attempts to debug this has not been successful.